# Initializing a perforce stream from another stream without copying files

Tags: git, perforce, perforce-stream

In git, when you run `git checkout -b <name>` while on `branch A`, assuming you had no pending changes, a new branch will be created and your workspace will switch to it. No files will be modified or copied, new branch will match `branch A` exactly.

I want to do the same with P4. I have a stream `trunk` which has about 2.5TB of data in it, currently sitting on `changelist 584` as the latest changelist. I want to create a new stream called `zero-four` where its initial state will look exactly the same as the state of the `trunk` at `changelist 584`. Basically `P4 checkout -b zero-four`.

The official way to do it is to create a new empty stream, `COPY` all the data you want in the initial changelist and submit it. You can see how that could be a pain when the branch you're working with has 2.5TB of data.

The way I currently plan to do it is to simply `MOVE` `trunk` into `zero-four`, submit `zero-four`, and then just move it back. I don't need to switch to `zero-four`, in this case, I actually don't want to.

Is there a saner way to do this? A command that will initialize a stream based on a state of another stream?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a "personal server" (a server created by `p4 init`) you can use a git-style workflow to create a new stream:

```
p4 switch -c <name>
```

Behind the scenes this does the equivalent of `p4 stream` and `p4 populate` before `switch`ing you to the new stream.  Since the new stream is identical to the stream you started in, the `p4 switch` doesn't re-transfer the files in the process of "syncing" you to the new stream.

If you're on a shared server, `switch -c` is disabled (because stream creation has overhead that most admins prefer to put a little friction in the way of by not making it a one-click command).  You can still do the equivalent commands though:

```
p4 stream -t development -P branchA <name>
p4 populate -r -S <name>
p4 switch <name>
```

See also `p4 copy -v` and `p4 integ -v`, which will open the files for branch (rather than instantly committing them like `populate` does) but without syncing them to your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you are looking for is [p4 populate](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_populate.html)

In this case, you would create the stream and then you would run `p4 populate`
to replicate all the files into the new stream, without needing to sync them locally and copy.
If you are doing this in P4V, you can just check the box at the bottom of the stream creation dialog that says "Branch files from parent on stream creation"

Hope that helps!